# Gridview control for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and rewriting a webform app to MVC. In my webform, I have asp.net control, GRIDVIEW. Can I add asp.net gridview to MVC? If not, what is the alternative solution?

Comment: No, you can't use a GridView directly in MVC.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use web form controls ( i.e. `<asp:GridView />`, `<asp:ListView />`, `<asp:Label />`) in MVC projects. No massive ViewState thank god lol.

**Alternatives**:

I personally like [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) . You can use the NuGet Package manager to find packages that will help you wire up DataTables with MVC by simply typing "datatables mvc" in the search. I have used [DataTables.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataTables.AspNet.Mvc5/) in a couple projects and have been happy with it so far.

Another way, might be to use the Microsoft [WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx) (System.Web.Helpers namespace). I have used this in a couple project as well, and it seems to to the job. Here is an [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/webgrid-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) of its use.